# How could Hom sets not be disjoint in category theory

Tags: category-theory, definition

I have came across some comments saying that in category theory, Hom-sets are NOT necessarily supposed to be disjoint, but I don’t see how one could manipulate such a category theory. Indeed, in the definition of the composition of two arrows, it is required to know from which Hom-sets the arrows are coming from, to be able to compose them. So in such a theory, we could imagine that the composition of two arrows depends on if we regard them as part of one Hom-set or another one… it’s problematic, because $f\circ g$ would not mean anything, depending on how we look at $f$ and $g$. Similarly, in the definition of a functor $F$, if we have $f \colon X \longrightarrow Y$ and $f \colon A \longrightarrow B$, then $F(f)$ is supposed to be such that $F(f):F(X)\longrightarrow F(Y)$ and $F(f) \colon F(A) \longrightarrow F(B)$ wich also is problematic no? It adds many things to be checked for each definitions and manipulations. Is this theory still usable and equivalent to a theory with disjoint Hom-sets?

Thanks for any answer you could give me,

Maxime

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are correct in saying that $f\circ g$ would be ambiguous notation in such a category. But composition is just a function $\hom(a,b)\times \hom(b,c)\to \hom(a,c)$, and generally speaking these homsets can be anything, including non-disjoint. For every ordered triple $(a,b,c)$ you have such a 'composition', as part of the definition of a category.

Comment: The models that construct a category are things the user of that category should not be worried about. You take the arrows and objects and functors and have fun with them; 'the' underlying set representation given to you by a set theorist is mostly none of your concern. This is my understanding of the matter. For example, I recall using a category where the arrows were 'implemented' at the set level by $n\times m$ matrices, of all things. If the 'same' matrix represents an arrow between two different objects, who cares? All I need to see are the two arrows

Comment: I think good notation for such a category would not allow $f$ to denote an arrow $X\to Y$ and $A\to B$. But rather, say there are two arrows $f,g$, that are 'represented' by the same element of $\hom(X,Y)\cap\hom(A,B)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers !

Comment: Doesn't the definition of a category come with functions assigning source and target to any morphism? If so hom-sets are necessarily disjoint, since any element $f\in hom(a,b)\cap hom(x,y)$ has both source $a$ and $x$ (showing $a=x$) and target $b$ and $y$ (showing $b=y$)... In other words: the datum of a morphism should always incorporate its source and target.

Comment: @JonasLinssen I think there are different definitions, and as you show the answer to the question depends on the choice of definition. For example, the definition in Leinster - *Basic Category Theory* allows for identical hom-sets (and does not mention sources nor targets). Wikipedia uses source- and target-functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A category $\newcommand{\cat}{\mathcal}\cat{C}$ can be defined as follows:

> 1. We have a class of objects $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$.
> 2. We have for every two objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\cat{C}$ a set $\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}} \Hom_{\cat{C}}(x, y)$.
> 3. We have for any three objects $X$, $Y$, $Z$ a composition map
>    $$
>      μ_{X, Y, Z}
>      \colon
>      \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, Y) × \Hom_{\cat{C}}(Y, Z)
>      \longrightarrow
>      \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, Z) \,.
>    $$
>
> These data must satisfy the following conditions:
>
> - There exists for every object $X$ of $\cat{C}$ an element $1_X ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, X)$ with
>
>   - $\mu_{X, X, Y}(1_X, f) = f$ for every $f ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, Y)$, and
>   - $\mu_{X, Y, Y}(f, 1_Y) = f$ for every $f ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, Y)$.
> - For have for any four objects $W$, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ the equality
>   $$
>       μ_{W, Y, Z}( μ_{W, X, Y}(f, g), h )
>       =
>       μ_{W, X, Z}( f, μ_{X, Y, Z}(g, h))
>     $$
>   for all $f ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(W, X)$, $g ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, Y)$ and $h ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(Y, Z)$.

This definition doesn’t require $\Hom$-sets to be disjoint.
For convenience, it is nevertheless common to introduce the standard notions:

- Once we have specified two objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\cat{C}$, we can introduce synonyms for “$f ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, Y)$”.
  We often write “$f \colon X \to Y$”, or “$f$ is a morphism from $X$ to $Y$”, or that “$f$ is a morphism with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$” instead.
  However, we need to keep in mind that this is just semantic sugar to make things easier to read.
- Given objects $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ and elements $f ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, Y)$ and $g ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(Y, Z)$, the element  $μ_{X, Y, Z}(f, g)$ is denoted by $g ∘ f$.
  This is an an abuse of notation/operator overloading.
  But since we have specified which objects $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ we are working over, this shouldn’t lead to problems.

> Similarly, in the definition of a functor $F$, if we have $f \colon X \to Y$ and $f \colon A \to B$, then $F(f)$ is supposed to be such that $F(f) \colon F(X) \to F(Y)$ and $F(f) \colon F(A) \to F(B)$

We define a functor as follows:

> Let $\cat{C}$ and $\cat{D}$ be two categories.
> A functor $F$ from $\cat{C}$ to $\cat{D}$ consists of
>
> 1. a map $F_0 \colon \mathrm{Ob}(\cat{C}) \to \mathrm{Ob}(\cat{D})$,
> 2. for every two objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\cat{C}$ a map $F_{X, Y} \colon \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, Y) \to \Hom_{\cat{D}}(F_0(X), F_0(Y))$.
>
> These data must satisfy the following two conditions:
>
> - $F_{X, X}(1_X) = 1_{F_0(X)}$ for every object $X$ of $\cat{C}$.
> - $F_{X, Z}(g ∘ f) = F_{Y, Z}(g) ∘ F_{X, Y}(f)$ for ever three objects $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ and all $f ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(X, Y)$ and $g ∈ \Hom_{\cat{C}}(Y, Z)$.

As usual, we abbreviate $F_0$ by $F$.
If we have specified which two objects $X$ and $Y$ we are working with, then we can also abbreviate $F_{X, Y}$ by $F$.

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I seek :)

Answer (score 4):

To make a long story short, if we don’t require the Hom sets to be disjoint, then we slightly change the definition of a category.

When we know hom sets are disjoint, we have a single partial function $a, b \mapsto a \circ b$.

When we don’t know hom sets are disjoint, we require an indexed family of composition operators $\circ_{A, B, C} : Hom(B, C) \times Hom(A, B) \to Hom(A, C)$. We typically suppress the subscript when it is clear from context which $A, B$, and $C$ are being referred to.

It should be noted that when we work with a category $C$ where the Hom sets are not necessarily disjoint, we can construct a category $C’$ which is isomorphic to $C$ where the Hom sets are disjoint. We define $Obj(C’) = Obj(C)$ and, for all $A, B \in Obj(C’)$, $Hom_{C’}(A, B) = \{(A, B, f) \mid f \in Hom_C(A, B)\}$. Composition is defined in the obvious way.

So there is really not much at stake when deciding whether to require Hom sets to be disjoint, except that it’s annoying to have to check it.

Comment: Alright! Great answer